# Employer Search View needs modification

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

In my [CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/george-stocker), I have the following summary:

[image: CV Summary]

---

In the employer search results, it shows up like this:

[image: employersearchresults]

---

The problem is that a **...** is added after my text, which *drastically* changes the tone of what I'm writing.

To denote "There's more here to see", I think there ought to be another indicator:

> *`[...]`*

placed **below** the line, instead of appending it into the end of the line.

Comment: I agree.  With ellipsis it reads like you're trailing off as if to add "sort of".

Comment: And for anyone that knows me, they find out very quickly that I'm not a *sort of* person. :-D