# Careers CV - Results Optimization

Tags: discussion, jobs, cv

I know Careers is young and still in beta, but I'm wondering if anybody out there (read "the creators") have any suggestions as to how to construct your CV for the best results.

I'm looking for suggestions like 'Don't use World as your location', etc. I surely don't want to exagerate the truth or act like I'm trying to make myself sound better than I am...I just want to be sure I show up in the searches as often as I can for the positions that are right for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **Use as many generic tags for your work experience as possible.**

   > I am a C# developer of Winforms and
   >   Webforms and ASP.NET MVC stripes; but
   >   that's not all I do. On my CV, I make
   >   sure to include the generic `.NET` tag
   >   as well as `Winforms` `ASP.NET`
   >   `ASP.NET MVC` and `C#`.
2. **Don't have Dislikes showing**.

   > If you can't say anything nice, don't
   >   say anything at all. And please, don't
   >   say, "I have [no pathologies](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/anelson) that
   >   keep me from working with others."
   >   That's a red flag in of itself.
3. **If it's hard to read, it won't be read.**

   > Format, format format. Make it look
   >   pretty.
4. **Show me the Numbers.**

   > **Give me the numbers. If you've increased effeciency in the software
   >   you've worked on, I want to know by
   >   how much. If you've increased sales, I
   >   want percents or dollar signs.**
5. **Work in Popular technologies**

   > If you're a `R` programming language
   >   guy, chances are you won't find much
   >   work.  Take a look at the [TIOBE
   >   Software Programming Trends](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) and
   >   start learning a language at the top
   >   of that list.
6. **Include particulars**

   > If you've worked with SQL Server, say
   >   so. Don't just say "SQL".
7. **Have a catchy Bio Line**

   > If you look at my [bio line](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/george-stocker),
   >   you'll see  that it's short, sweet,
   >   and to the point. Do that.  **Don't ramble.**
8. **Choose an Exciting Work Location**

   > There will probably be a lot less
   >   employers looking for Developers in
   >   Topeka, Kansas than there would be in
   >   Washington, DC or New York, NY.  Pick
   >   locations where you want to work; but
   >   pick smart locations.  In a recession
   >   / depression, the mobile worker gets
   >   the job.  You *have* to be willing to
   >   move if you aren't in a metropolitan
   >   area. Period.

---

Here are my stats:

20 CV Search Hits
76 Public CV Views
3 Employer CV Views

Comment: I hate Markdown. How the hell do I get it not to reformat my numbers to all ones?  That seems like a bug.

Comment: @George ...what kind of responses have you received from your CV, if you don't mind me asking. Obviously mine has gone un-noticed. Yours looks much more 'travelled'

Comment: Justin: Do you have a link to your CV?

Comment: @George http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Justin-Niessner

Comment: @George - I know it still needs quite a bit of work. I want to make sure I focus on the right parts...rather than spend time focusing on the low return items.

Answer (score 1):

When an employer searches resumes, he or she will see only **the first ~195 characters** of your biography on the search results page. So make those characters count.

Here is how George's looks, for example. Note how the text is **perfectly** tuned for that character limit.

[image]

Comment: Ha. Also just noticed that if you don't terminate the markdown bold in the first 195 characters, then your "favorites" will be bold. I'm sure that bug will be fixed at some point, though. :-)

Comment: That's definitely good to know. I did a quick rip from one of my cover letters thinking that the whole field might be shown...looks like I was wrong. I know the next couple of things to tweak now.

Comment: I put in a bug about this a while back. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27784/employer-search-view-needs-modification